# IESetProtectedModeCookie function not found in Iepmapi.h

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

IESetProtectedModeCookie function not found in Iepmapi.h
But when i call function using LoadLibrary technique with **Ieframe.dll** then it create entry in **LOW** folder of **cookies** but get **GP** after creating entry.
How?

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: pfnIESetProtectedModeCookie(L"http://contoso.com", L"CookieName", L"ID=asadwddw:U=ecd9af447f075b3e:FF=1:FFL=1:LD=en:TM=1358162464:LM=1358163519:S=ItXyyYjSJc3sz8VC;expires=Sat, 08-Jan-2014 00:00:00 GMT", NULL);      **I dont know but i think its issue of calling convetion**

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `IESetProtectedModeCookie`, you can see that it is only supported in IE8 and above.

Try defining `_WIN32_IE=_WIN32_IE_IE80` and call the function normally instead of using `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: can you please post reference code for same i am doing what you have told but its not working...

Comment: After doing what I suggested is `IESetProtectedModeCookie` found in iepmapi.h?

Comment: No, I define `_WIN32_IE=_WIN32_IE_IE80` but `IESetProtectedModeCookie` function not showing in Iepmapi.lib or Iepmapi.h...

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you have the right version of the Windows SDK?

Comment: Yes Its version problem, Visual Studio 2012 Solve all my problems...Thanx Buddy for your valuable suggestions.